# Python imports and unit tests

Tags: python

I am trying to build a Python package/library for the first time. So far I have these files:

```
src
  Accentizer2
    __init__.py
    Accentizer.py
    Annotation.py
test
  test_1.py
```

File contents:

Accentizer.py:

```py
from Annotation import Annotation # this is where the error occurs


class Accentizer:
    x = 10
```

Annotation.py:

```py
class Annotation:
    Variants = []
```

test_1.py:

```py
from src.Accentizer2.Accentizer import Accentizer
```

When I run test_1.py, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..\tests\test_1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.Accentizer2.Accentizer import Accentizer
  File "..\src\Accentizer2\Accentizer.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Annotation import Annotation
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Annotation'
```

When I run Accentizer.py, it runs ok.

What am I missing? What is the conventional way of linking tests to code under test?

Changing the import statement in `Accentizer.py` to the line below fixes the error:

```py
from src.Accentizer2.Accentizer import Accentizer
```

But then I get the error 'src is not a module name' after I build and install the Accentizer2 package and try to import it in another project.

Answer (score 1):

Several things are a little off in here

### Current problem

in your `Accentizer.py` you are trying to import a global package `Annotation`. However, the `Annotation.py` is a local file (local to the package/folder).

Assuming your `src` folder is in the `sys.path`, a correct way of doing it (given your folder structure) is either have a global or local import. **Note: the names global and local are not really standard :)**

#### Global import

This just imports the package, and provides a fully qualified path during import. Assumption is that `src` is in the path.

```py
from src.Accentizer2.Annotation import Annotation

class Accentizer:
    x = 10
```

#### Local import

This one doesn't care about where everything is located, and uses `.` to refer to the current folder. You can also use `..` to refer to parent, `...` to grandparent, etc.

```py
from .Annotation import Annotation

class Accentizer:
    x = 10
```

### Stylistic problems

#### `src` folder

It is non-pythonic to have a `src` folder. It is customary for a lot of languages, but not some much for python

#### Naming convention

Generally, you don't wanna name the files the same as the class names. I would suggest having files `accentizer.py` and `annotation.py` with classes `Accentizer` and `Annotation` respectively. The reasoning is that having the same name for class and file *might* break the import process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the ```src``` folder following this guide: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#creating-the-package-files

Comment: It still remains a mystery to me, how it knows what ```src``` is in ```from src...``` in test_1.py. ```src``` is a sibling of ```test```. Does it also look in sibling folders?

Comment: Also, having `from src...` in every test_X.py is not ideal. Where do we normally put tests and how do we reference code under test? I am thinking of putting tests next to source files being tested, but then I would have to specifically exclude tests from the package.

Comment: You can have either top level `sys.path.append('YOUR PATH TO src HERE')`, or you need to specify `PYTHONPATH` environment variable

Comment: `from src...` is not really a mystery, as long as it is either in the `PYTHONPATH` or in the `sys.path` or in the current running directory, it is available. Also, about the tutorial -- the *parent* of the `src` folder in there should not be in the system path. In the example you referenced, the `src` is not the package name, but the *root* name where the package is located. Either way it is fine, as long as you don't force the user to have `import src.package_name` :)